# Cannot access ftp site through WAN

Tags: networking, ftp

i was trying to establish an ftp connection on my LAN and WAN , i use windows 8 , i configured the IIS , and opened port 21 , actually disabled firewall , i created a new user to access my ftp folder 'A' , it worked fine on LAN by accessing

```
   ftp://192.168.1.10 (my local ip),from any pc on my LAN.
```

The problem is , i am trying to access through ftp but this time from WAN , i configured the router to port forward to my LAN (192.168.1.10) , i looked up my static ip , now i have a login panel

```
           ftp://393.32.3.2(random ip) when it comes to authentification i used the user i created but it is not working , any ideas ?
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? I am facing with the same thing

Answer (score 0):

FTP uses both port 20 and 21. You have only port forwarded port 21 which is used to initiate and control connections to FTP servers.

This means you will be able to connect to your FTP server and log in, but it will not be able to transfer any files because that uses port 20.

Hope this helped!
-Kad

Answer (score 0):

you must configure in your router ports 1025-3500 forwarding to yours server ex: 192.168.0.100
you must configure in your router ports 21(all protocols tcp&udp) forwarding to yours server ex: 192.168.0.100